# Visual studio Debug assertion failed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

This error keeps coming up every time my program finishes and I have no Idea why
The line it specifies(106) contains this:

```
getline(iss, tmp, ',');
```

the method the line is in just reads a .txt file, extracts the info and I use it to create an object with that info.

thanks

[image: error]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Please post **all** of the relevant code including variable declarations and initialisations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't refer to your line 106, but to line 106 in the header `<xmemory0>`.

That line contains the code shown after "Expression:", which checks that a large memory block being deallocated is properly page aligned. And it isn't.

So some pointer that is free'd at the end of the program is not the correct pointer to free. That's all we can tell from the message.

*You* might want to click the Retry button to enter the debugger and check where the call is coming from.

Comment: the thing is, when I enter the debugger it just crashes